# Suitecrm - php code in pdf template

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to add a php code in my pdf template. Here is my use case

First is I have a dropdown on my own module:
[image: sample screenshot]

Then what I want to have is on my pdf template, I want to have php condition base on the value of my dropdown e.g

```
if($client_type == "renewal") echo "x"; else echo "y";
```

Will this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a placeholder in the pdf template, for example:

```
%%renewal_value%%
```

Then you can work out your required value like you described, but rather than echoing the value use **str_replace**

```
$bean = BeanFactory::getBean('AOS_PDF_Templates', 'some-id');
$value = ($client_type == "renewal") "x": "y";
str_replace('%%renewal_value%%', $value, $bean->description);
```