# Logic hook in Contacts modulle

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I need the next thing in SuiteCRM : when i save a contact (fill his first name and last name) i need to have in one field shortened first name. For example, instead John Smith i need to have J.Smith.

I did the next code:

```
class contactShortName
{
    function getShortName($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        $bean->short_name = substr($bean->first_name,0,1) . '.' .  $bean->last_name;
        $bean->save();
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. Help please.

Comment: Have you added this to the custom/modules/Contacts/logic_hooks.php file?

Comment: @johnmccuk yes, of course. and did quick repair and build

Comment: you definitely don't need the $bean->save() part, this could cause infinite loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with the information provided, the custom/modules/Contacts/logic_hooks.php file should contain something similar to:

```
$hook_version = 1;
$hook_array = Array();
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array();    
$hook_array['before_save'][] = [1, 'Set short name', 'path/to/contactShortName.php', 'contactShortName', 'getShortName'];
```

And the file should be

```
class contactShortName
{
    function getShortName($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        $bean->short_name = substr($bean->first_name,0,1) . '.' .  $bean->last_name;
    }
}
```

That should work...

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: is the logic hook firing? if you do a var_dump() within the getShortName method is it showing?

Comment: yes, i tried just for the test sth like $bean->short_name = $bean->last_name and it's worked. But when i add substr function, it is not working

Comment: only thing I can think of is that since short_name is a custom field, it might actually be $bean->short_name_c

Comment: no, names of the fields are just for example. when i code $bean->short_name = $bean->last_name i see in field short_name the value of  last_name

Comment: yes, but does that value save rather than just show in a var_dump? If it does save, I'm out of ideas :-(

Comment: well, i found the solution. I print in Russian, and a Russian letter is taken as 2 symbols, not 1 as English. That's why i need do sth like substr($bean->first_name,0,2) to print the first letter. Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: can i ask one more question? How can i add php library in logic hook? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you can't use namespaces, so just use require_once at the top of your class and use normally. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. and where i should place a library file? i mean in which folder?

Comment: If your manually adding it, wherever you want, something like custom/libraries or something similar. You should look into using composer rather than manually adding libraries though. Composer would add all libraries in a folder called vendor.

Comment: @ChickChirik If you have to deal with UTF-8 characters, you may want to check out PHP's multi-byte functions that are written to deal with exactly those.
For example: https://secure.php.net/manual/function.mb-substr.php should allow you to get the the first character with `mb_substr($bean->first_name,0,1)` regardless of whether the first character is 1 byte long (ascii), 2 bytes (e.g. cyrillic) or even 4 bytes.

mb functions usually need the php package _php-mbstring_ to be installed.

Comment: @johnmccuk can you help me please with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860526/suitecrm-php-code-in-pdf-template

I need to add php code in pdf template, but i didn't understand where i should store the code you've shown. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That depends on how you want to use it, if it's multiple beans, it should be in a scheduler. If it's an individual bean, either in a logic hook or maybe a button on the form.  Whatever way write a custom class and just require_once from wherever you need it.

Comment: You should avoid logic_hooks.php and instead use logic hook extensions, which are less likely to be overwritten by other code or packages.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/